# Teamcity REST API issue in with POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, teamcity

I am trying to create a TeamCity project from .NET Core. I have written the code below but when I am trying to run the code I get an error.

Code:

```
public void CreateProject(string name, string newProjectId, string parentProjectId)
{
    InvokeTeamCityApi(() => _apiClient.CreateProject(new NewProjectDescription
    {
        Name = name,
        Id = newProjectId,
        SourceProject = new GetProjectResponse
        {
            Id = _toolContext.HostingContext.TeamCityProjectTemplate
        },
        ParentProject = new GetProjectResponse
        {
            Id = parentProjectId
        },
        CopyAllAssociatedSettings = true,
    }));
}
```

Error:

> 403 Forbidden: CSRF Header X-TC-CSRF-Token does not match CSRF session value

Also I did a Google search and I tried adding the header origin but I dont have access to disable the internal teamcity properties to disable CSRF check.

So I am passing the token X-tc-CSRF-Token in the request but it says the value doesn't match. How can I solve this issue?

Note: I am getting this issue only when I am using bearer token and with basic auth it works fine.

Comment: Any idea on how can i solve this

Comment: Related: [REST API Posting two request simultaneously with different properties fails with 403 status code due to CSRF check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56780171/1364007)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue when upgrading from TeamCity 10 to TeamCity 2022 and eventually managed to find out how to fix it. Importantly, I didn't have to have access the internal TeamCity properties to disable the [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) check as I figured that it's not a bad thing to have the extra layer of security.

Things that were probably important that I changed:

- I generated an [access token](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-your-user-profile.html#Managing+Access+Tokens) for the account that I was using to access the REST API so I wouldn't need to put my password in the code. The access token can be associated with more restrictive permissions than your own account.
- Using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient), authorisation is achieved by adding a default header (via the [`DefaultHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders) property) with the name `"Authorization"` and value `"Bearer {apiToken}"`.
- I read the [`/authenticationTest.html?csrf`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/csrf-protection.html#Implications+for+CORS+clients) endpoint to get a CSRF token then add that value as a default header ([`"X-TC-CSRF-Token"`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/csrf-protection.html)). It's also possible to use the `"tc-csrf-token"` header in the same way.

Note that because the `"Authorization"` and `"X-TC-CSRF-Token"`/`"tc-csrf-token"` headers are added as default headers, there's no need to do this explicitly on every HTTP (GET, POST ,DELETE, etc.) method.

---

Here's some sample code which covers all of the above.

```
public class Sample
{
    private readonly string _baseUrl;

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public Sample(string baseUrl, string accessToken)
    {
        _baseUrl = baseUrl;

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

        var csrfToken = get("/authenticationTest.html?csrf");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-TC-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
    }

    public void CreateProject(string id, string name)
    {
        post("/app/rest/projects", $"<newProjectDescription id=\"{id}\" name=\"{name}\" />");
    }

    private string get(string relativeUrl)
    {
        var getTask = _httpClient.GetAsync(_baseUrl + relativeUrl);
        getTask.Wait();

        var response = getTask.Result;

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        readTask.Wait();

        using ( var stream = readTask.Result )
        using ( var reader = new StreamReader(stream) )
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    private void post(string relativeUrl, string data)
    {
        using ( var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") )
        {
            var postTask = _httpClient.PostAsync(_baseUrl + relativeUrl, content);
            postTask.Wait();

            var response = postTask.Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            readTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Call it using, e.g.

```
// Change these according to your situation
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8111";
var accessToken = "1234567890";

var sample = new Sample(baseUrl, accessToken);
sample.CreateProject("ProjectID", "ProjectName");
```

---

Note that this is just a sample to get you on your feet: I've kept the code short by taking various shortcuts in the code (e.g. the `HttpClient` should really be one static HttpClient for the application: see [Guidelines for using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines) on learn.microsoft.com).